# loop over fields of a C# object

Tags: c#

In a project there is a reporting class as follows:

```
public class ReportRowDataContract
{   
    public ReportDataDataContract ReportData1 { get; set; }

    public ReportDataDataContract ReportData2 { get; set; }

    public ReportDataDataContract ReportData3 { get; set; }

    public ReportDataDataContract ReportData4 { get; set; }

    public ReportDataDataContract ReportData5 { get; set; }

    public ReportDataDataContract ReportData6 { get; set; }        
}
```

Then there is a method that works with objects from the above class.  Here is the first part of this method:

```
public ReportGrid(List<ReportRowDataContract> items , List<ReportDataDataContract> summaryData)
            : base(items)
        {

                passedInSummaryData = summaryData;

                if (items[0].ReportData1 != null)
                {
                    if (items[0].ReportData1.DecimalValue != null)
                    {

                        Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData1.DecimalValue).Titled(items[0].ReportData1.Name).Encoded(false).
                            Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(
                                m => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(@m.ReportData1.DisplayFormat)) ? Convert.ToDecimal(@m.ReportData1.DecimalValue).ToString("N") : Convert.ToDecimal(@m.ReportData1.DecimalValue).ToString(@m.ReportData1.DisplayFormat));

                        if (items[0].ReportData1.SumValue || items[0].ReportData1.AvgValue)
                        {
                            displaySummary = true;
                            SummaryData.Add(
                                new ReportDataDataContract
                                    {
                                        Name = items[0].ReportData1.Name,
                                        AvgValue = items[0].ReportData1.AvgValue,
                                        DecimalValue = 0
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                    else if (items[0].ReportData1.IntValue != null)
                    {
                        Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData1.IntValue).Titled(items[0].ReportData1.Name);
                        if (items[0].ReportData1.SumValue || items[0].ReportData1.AvgValue)
                        {
                            displaySummary = true;
                            SummaryData.Add(
                                new ReportDataDataContract
                                    {
                                        Name = items[0].ReportData1.Name,
                                        AvgValue = items[0].ReportData1.AvgValue,
                                        IntValue = 0
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData1.StringValue).Titled(items[0].ReportData1.Name);
                    }
                }
                if (items[0].ReportData2 != null)
                {
                    if (items[0].ReportData2.DecimalValue != null)
                    {
                    Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData2.DecimalValue).Titled(items[0].ReportData2.Name).Encoded(false).
                       Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(
                           m => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(@m.ReportData2.DisplayFormat)) ? Convert.ToDecimal(@m.ReportData2.DecimalValue).ToString("N") : Convert.ToDecimal(@m.ReportData2.DecimalValue).ToString(@m.ReportData1.DisplayFormat));

                    if (items[0].ReportData2.SumValue || items[0].ReportData2.AvgValue)
                        {
                            displaySummary = true;
                            SummaryData.Add(
                                new ReportDataDataContract
                                    {
                                        Name = items[0].ReportData2.Name,
                                        AvgValue = items[0].ReportData2.AvgValue,
                                        DecimalValue = 0
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                    else if (items[0].ReportData2.IntValue != null)
                    {
                        Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData2.IntValue).Titled(items[0].ReportData2.Name);
                        if (items[0].ReportData2.SumValue || items[0].ReportData2.AvgValue)
                        {
                            displaySummary = true;
                            SummaryData.Add(
                                new ReportDataDataContract
                                    {
                                        Name = items[0].ReportData2.Name,
                                        AvgValue = items[0].ReportData2.AvgValue,
                                        IntValue = 0
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData2.StringValue).Titled(items[0].ReportData2.Name);
                    }

                }
```

This method consists of code that repeats itself out to ReportData6, changing only the ReportData field name with each repetition.  Is there a way that this method can be rewritten to process each ReportData field by looping somehow?  Besides making for a shorter method, this would be extremely useful to have in order to avoid manually updating the method if additional ReportData fields need to be added to the ReportRowDataContract class in the future.

**Edit #1:** I am fairly new to C# so detailed answers of how to go about this would be immensely helpful.

**Edit #2:** Thanks to Zohar Peled's post below, the following code feels very close.  However, `m.ReportData1` is causing problems in the AddGridColumn() method.  The error message is *'ReportRowDataContract' does not contain a definition for 'item'...*
I tried passing in ReportData 1 as a second argument when AddGridColumn() is called, but to no avail.  Is there a way to modify the code so it works?

code that calls method:

```
    // create columns for grid
    AddGridColumn(items[0].ReportData1);
    AddGridColumn(items[0].ReportData2);
    AddGridColumn(items[0].ReportData3);
    AddGridColumn(items[0].ReportData4);
    AddGridColumn(items[0].ReportData5);
    AddGridColumn(items[0].ReportData6);
```

method:

```
private void AddGridColumn(ReportDataDataContract item)
{
    if (item != null)
        {
            if (item.DecimalValue != null)
            {                        
                Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData1.DecimalValue).Titled(item.Name).Encoded(false).
                    Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(
                        m => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(@m.ReportData1.DisplayFormat)) ?
                            Convert.ToDecimal(@m.ReportData1.DecimalValue).ToString("N") :
                            Convert.ToDecimal(@m.ReportData1.DecimalValue).ToString(@m.ReportData1.DisplayFormat));

                if (item.SumValue || item.AvgValue)
                {
                    displaySummary = true;
                    SummaryData.Add(
                        new ReportDataDataContract
                            {
                                Name = item.Name,
                                AvgValue = item.AvgValue,
                                DecimalValue = 0
                            });
                }
            }
            else if (item.IntValue != null)
            {
                Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData1.IntValue).Titled(item.Name);
                if (item.SumValue || item.AvgValue)
                {
                    displaySummary = true;
                    SummaryData.Add(
                        new ReportDataDataContract
                            {
                                Name = item.Name,
                                AvgValue = item.AvgValue,
                                IntValue = 0
                            });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData1.StringValue).Titled(item.Name);
            }
        }
}
```

**Edit #3:** This is the ReportDataDataContract class definiton:

```
public class ReportDataDataContract
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public string StringValue { get; set; }        
    public decimal? DecimalValue { get; set; }        
    public int? IntValue { get; set; }        
    public bool SumValue { get; set; }        
    public bool AvgValue { get; set; }        
    public int? Index { get; set; }    
    public string DisplayFormat { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: replace the `ReportDataX` fields with a single `List<ReportDataContract>`.  then you can loop over that `List`

Comment: This sounds like a job for an array.  Why can't `ReportRowDataContract` just have a single property of `IList<ReportDataDataContract>`?

Comment: Instead of bunch of properties, you could refactor your `ReportRowDataContract` class to contain a single `IEnumerable<ReportDataDataContract>` property and enumerate over it. Alternatively, use Reflection.

Comment: var properties= typeof(items[0].GetType()).GetProperties();

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, when you get to the point of numbering your properties (Foo1, Foo2, ...), nine times out of ten you should instead be using a collection/array/IEnumerable/.... That is the case here as well.

Comment: What's `m` in this lambda expression? In my code example I've seen `ReportData1` and changed the lambda to `m => dataContranct.DecimalValue`, where `dataContract` is the item passed to the method. Did you try that?

Comment: @Zohar Peled - It appears to think that `m` is a `ReportRowDataContract`.  Here is the error message: 'ReportRowDataContract' does not contain a definition for 'item' and no extension method 'item' accepting a first argument of type 'ReportRowDataContract' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What happens if instead `m => m.ReportData1.DecimalValue` you do `m => item.DecimalValue`?

Comment: When I do `m => item.DecimalValue`: on the first pass through the method it works fine.  However, on the second pass through it throws an exception with these details: `System.ArgumentException  {"Column 'item.DecimalValue' already exists in the grid"}`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add an indexed property like this to ReportRowDataContract in order to essentially access the ReportData values as an indexed property?

```
public ReportDataDataContract this[int i]
{
   get
   {
      return new ReportDataDataContract[] { ReportData1, ReportData2, ReportData3, ReportData4, ReportData5, ReportData6 }[i];
   }
}
```

The you can use `items[0][i].SumValue`, for example, instead of `items[0].ReportData1.SumValue`.

Comment: Your post was quite helpful for the looping I ended up using in the final solution.  Thanks for the code sample.

Answer (score -1):

If you can, you should simply change the `ReportRowDataContract` to only hold a single property that is an array of `ReportDataDataContract`. Then you can use a simple loop for each of the data contracts.

If you can't change the `ReportRowDataContract` table, you could use a method that takes in an argument of type `ReportDataDataContract` and have all the repeated code there - and just call it one time for each property.

The method should look something like that (based on the code you've posted):

```
void DoSomething(ReportDataDataContract dataContranct)
{
    if (dataContranct != null)
    {
        if (dataContranct.DecimalValue != null)
        {

            Columns.Add(m => dataContranct.DecimalValue).Titled(dataContranct.Name).Encoded(false).
                Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(
                    m => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(@dataContranct.DisplayFormat)) ? 
                        Convert.ToDecimal(@dataContranct.DecimalValue).ToString("N") : 
                        Convert.ToDecimal(@dataContranct.DecimalValue).ToString(@dataContranct.DisplayFormat));

            if (dataContranct.SumValue || dataContranct.AvgValue)
            {
                displaySummary = true;
                SummaryData.Add(
                    new ReportDataDataContract
                        {
                            Name = dataContranct.Name,
                            AvgValue = dataContranct.AvgValue,
                            DecimalValue = 0
                        });
            }
        }
        else if (dataContranct.IntValue != null)
        {
            Columns.Add(m => dataContranct.IntValue).Titled(dataContranct.Name);
            if (dataContranct.SumValue || dataContranct.AvgValue)
            {
                displaySummary = true;
                SummaryData.Add(
                    new ReportDataDataContract
                        {
                            Name = dataContranct.Name,
                            AvgValue = dataContranct.AvgValue,
                            IntValue = 0
                        });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Columns.Add(m => mdataContranct.StringValue).Titled(dataContranct.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change `ReportRowDataContract` so I'll have to try your second suggestion.  Can you post an example of what such a method would look like and how to use it?

Comment: I've edited my answer with an untested example of the method.

Comment: Your sample code is super helpful.  Check out my Edit #2 above.  Got any ideas?

Comment: Dear second downvoter. Would you please explain your downvote, given the fact that the OP wrote a comment about how "super helpful" my code sample is?